# Select unrelated method calls on runtime

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns

We have the following scneario:

- Client (TIBCO)
- Service1 (Web Service)
- Service2 (Web Service)

The Client may want to call any method of any service at any time, and the number of services may change in the future.

We want to develop an intermediate Web Service with only (if possible) one method which depending on the arguments, would route the call to Service1, 2 or 'n', so we shield the Client from the number of services.

I've been trying to figure out if I could use a design pattern to solve this or if there is a common solution, but given that there's no relation between services whatsover (no common interface, different methods each with its own arguments), I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: How do you expect the client to "know" what arguments to pass for a new service? You're building a Facade, but are you only hiding the easy bit? That is: where the new service is, not what arguments it takes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is pretty simple. Just create a method which takes two string arguments: The service to invoke and the SOAP to send to it.

But Web Service makes this pretty complicated, especially when you want to use all the power of automatic service argument serialization. You would have to find a way on the client to intercept the generated SOAP for the real method call and reroute that to the "proxy method."

So one solution is to offer only services which takes lists of strings as arguments. That gives you a kind of "shell" service (like a Unix shell) where everything is a string. Since the API for all methods is now the same, the client can talk to anyone. But you lose the ability to convert Java objects to SOAP automatically.

The next approach is to use a proxy which just takes the SOAP messages and forwards them to different servers. That means the client just has to talk to a single server which seems to handle all kinds of SOAP requests.

The other solution is to ditch Web Service and use a protocol like JSON or REST which has a much more simple wire format and puts less strain on the data structures and code involved.